# Creating a table in RStudio with text in the row names and column names

Tags: r, rstudio, bioinformatics, data-analysis

I am looking to create a table to compare 4 different gene sets to see where there are overlaps between the different gene sets. 
I would like to refer to them as:

> 'BCG_validation'
>   'BCG_discovery'
>   'MTB_validation'
>   'MTB_discovery'

The code I have written so far is as follows:

```
mx.overlap <- matrix(rep(NA,16), ncol=4)
mx.overlap

colnames(mx.overlap) <- paste('BCG_validation', 'BCG_discovery',
'MTB_validation','MTB_discovery')

rownames(mx.overlap) <- paste('BCG_validation', 'BCG_discovery',       
'MTB_validation', 'MTB_discovery')
```

However, when I executed it, I received the error message:

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
>     length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent.

**Any ideas on how I can alter this code to successfully create the table?**

[image]

Where you can see [,1] all the way to 4, that is where I would like to see the headings so that when I enter 'View' I can visually see all the row names and column names.

Comment: Use `c()`, not `paste()`. `paste()` is joining all 4 labels into a single string (1 element), which does not match the number of needed row/column names (4 elements).

Answer (score 3):

wrong use of `?paste`, use `?c`

```
mx.overlap <- matrix(rep(NA,16), ncol=4)

colnames(mx.overlap) <- c('BCG_validation', 'BCG_discovery',
                              'MTB_validation','MTB_discovery')

rownames(mx.overlap) <- c('BCG_validation', 'BCG_discovery',       
                              'MTB_validation', 'MTB_discovery')

mx.overlap
```

---

you can also use `?dimnames` after matrix definition:

```
nm <- c('BCG_validation', 'BCG_discovery',
        'MTB_validation','MTB_discovery')

dimnames(mx.overlap) <- list(nm, nm)
```

---

Or even shorer use the `dimnames =` argument directly in matrix:

```
nm <- c('BCG_validation', 'BCG_discovery', 'MTB_validation', 'MTB_discovery')
mx.overlap <- matrix(rep(NA,16), ncol=4, dimnames = list(nm, nm))
```

Comment: I have just tried executing it again using your suggestion. It has worked indeed, thanks a lot!